# Can't select textbox in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to access the comment textbox in a generic huffington post artical. When I right click inspect element I get the following HTML code:

```
<div class="UFIInputContainer">
 <div class="_1cb _5yk1">
  <div class="_5yk2" tabindex="-2">
   <div class="_5rp7">
```

with the line `<div class="_1cb _5yk1">` highlighted.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
'''
Just pretend that I put in some code to log in to facebook
so I can actually post a comment on huffington post
'''
driver.get.('http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/worst-suicide-squad-reviews_us_57a1e213e4b0693164c34744?')
'''
Just a random artical about a movie
'''
comment_box = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('._1cb._5yk1')
'''
since this is a compound class I think I should use find_by_css_selector
'''
```

When I run this though, I get the error message: "no such element found". I have tried other methods of trying to get a hold of the comment textbox but I get the same error message and I am at a lost of how to access it. I am hoping somebody can shed some light on this problem.

edit: This is a more complete HTML code:

```
<html lang="en" id="facebook" class="svg ">
 <head>...</head>
  <body dir="ltr" class="plugin chrome webkit win x1 Locale_en_US">
   <div class="_li">
    <div class="pluginSkinLight pluginFontHelvetica">
     <div id="u_0_0">
      <div data-reactroot class="_56q9">
       <div class="_2pi8">
        <div class="_491z clearfix">...</div>
         <div spacing="medium" class="_4uyl _1zz8 _2392 clearfix" direction="left">
          <div class="_ohe lfloat">...</div>
          <div class>
           <div class="UFIInputContainer">
            <div class="_1cb _5yk1">
             <div class="_5yk2" tabindex="-2">
              <div class="_5rp7">
             </div>
            </div>
            <div class="UFICommentAttachmentButtons clearfix">...</div>
            <!-- react-empty: 39 -->
            <div class="_4uym">...</div>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
         ::after
```

Comment: The HTML does not show any thing about checkbox, could you share few more lines where you see `input` tag.

Comment: I looked through the HTML code and couldn't find any input tag in the adjacent code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to switch to the iframe containing the text box. Try the following approach, it should work:
Clicking the load comments button might be required first if load comment button is displayed

```
load_comment = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.comment-button.js-comment-button')
load_comment.click()
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.fb_ltr.fb_iframe_widget_lift'))
comment_box = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('._1cb._5yk1')
comment_box.send_keys('Test')
```

Comment: Thank you. The code brings me closer. When I enter the command: comment_box.click() it brings the curser onto the comment box, but when I send the command:  comment_box.send_keys('Test') I get the error: cannot focus element.

Comment: Try directly sending text to the comment_box without the `.click()` .

Comment: I am still getting the same error message unfortunately.

Comment: I tried the above code and it works fine. Try with Firefox driver. Your issue could be due to this bug - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=35

Comment: hmm... for firefox i don't get the error message but nothing goes though. I tried it out on my other computer though and it works fine on that. Thanks.